# NullReferenceException And not being able post data to database

Tags: html, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am developing a School Management Application using asp.net core MVC 2.2 and I have a problem with posting data from one particular textbox of a View to the database using entity framwork and I receive Erorr "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

This is my model:

```
public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="نام شاگرد")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false,ErrorMessage ="(0) را وارد کنید")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "لطفابیشتراز(1)حرف وارد نکنید  ")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "لطفاکمتراز(1)حرف واردنکنید")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "نام پدر")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "(0) را وارد کنید")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "لطفابیشتراز(1)حرف وارد نکنید  ")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "لطفاکمتراز(1)حرف واردنکنید")]
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "شماره تماس")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "(0) را وارد کنید")]
        
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "شماره تماس پدر")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "(0) را وارد کنید")]
        public int FatherPhone { get; set; }
        //[Display(Name = "ولایت")]
        //[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "(0) را وارد کنید")]
        public int? ProvinceId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "ولسوالی")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "(0) را وارد کنید")]
        public string District { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "قریه")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "(0) را وارد کنید")]

        public string Vilage { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "نمبر تذکره")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "(0) را وارد کنید")]
        public int NIC { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "نمبر مسلسل")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "(0) را وارد کنید")]
        public int EntranceNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = " سال ورود")] 
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "(0) را وارد کنید")]
        public DateTime EntranceYear { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "فیس")]
        public int GrantFee { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "لیله یا نهاری")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "(0) را وارد کنید")]
        public bool IsDaily { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "آدرس فعلی")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "(0) را وارد کنید")]
        public string CurrentAdress { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "آدرس دائمی")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "(0) را وارد کنید")]
        public string Permanent { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(ProvinceId))]
        public virtual Province Province { get; set; }
```

This is my Markup in View:

```
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label>ولایت</label>
                                    <select asp-for="ProvinceId" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">لطفا ولایت مربوطه را انتخاب کنید</option>
                                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Provinces)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
                                        }
                                        
                                    </select>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
```

This is my controller and EntityframWork Code whitin it

```
  public class StudentInformationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DOHMSDbContext database;
        public StudentInformationController(DOHMSDbContext database)
        {
            this.database = database;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult AddStudentInformation()
        {
            ViewBag.Provinces = database.Provinces.ToList();
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddStudentInformation(StudentInformationVm studentInformationVm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Student student = new Student()
                { Name =studentInformationVm.Name,
                  FatherName=studentInformationVm.FatherName,
                  FatherPhone=studentInformationVm.FatherPhone,
                  CurrentAdress=studentInformationVm.CurrentAdress,
                  District=studentInformationVm.District,
                  Phone=studentInformationVm.Phone,
                  Permanent=studentInformationVm.Permanent,
                  EntranceNumber=studentInformationVm.EntranceNumber,
                  GrantFee=studentInformationVm.GrantFee,
                  IsDaily=studentInformationVm.IsDaily,
                  NIC=studentInformationVm.NIC,
                  Vilage=studentInformationVm.Vilage,
                  ProvinceId=studentInformationVm.ProvinceId
                };
                database.Students.Add(student);
                database.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This is the screenshot of the Error
[My screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9JUX.png)

I have a database but can not store data in it please help me solve this problem thank you so much

Comment: Add a break point at the beginning of the action. It is possible that one of the properties of the view model being passed to your action is null. If the exception happens without reaching the action, they you might need to eliminate properties from your view model until you find out which property is causing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `AddStudentInformation` action use `ReturnRedirectToAction` instead `Return View("AddStudentInformation")`